# When is a scheme over an affine scheme affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $X$ be a scheme. Let ${\rm{Spec}}(R)$ be an affine scheme for some ring $R$. Suppose that there is a morphism of schemes $f:X\rightarrow{\rm{Spec}}(R)$. What properties should $f$ have so that $X$ is also an affine scheme? Or what conditions can make $X$ affine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is an affine morphism, then $X$ is affine by definition.

This is an "if and only if". If $X$ is affine, the so is $f$. See theorem 7.3.7 in Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, or [29.11.3 and 29.11.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01S5) in the Stacks Project.

Comment: So in particular if $f$ is a closed immersion, for example.